# php mysql SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' doesn't work with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am migrating my site into php mysqli from php mysql_* methods.

I had following code that did the job:

> mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'");

Without this query my string characters (in Georgian language) were written with question marks.
For example it was written ????????? instead of გამარჯობა

So since it did its job I was happy, but now I cannot do the same with mysqli.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

Can anyone please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not recommended to use mysqli query in order to set names but rather [mysqli::set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}

but does not work.

Comment: OK I made it into work. GREAT THANK YOU. I will accept your answer ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`mysqli_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)**

> This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysqli_query()
>   to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended.

However, to set collation, you will still have to use the `SET NAMES` query.

Answer (score 1):

`http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php`

or

`mysqli->set_charset("utf8")`

Answer (score 1):

## A PHP feature request/bug report was filed...

See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52267 which garnered the response from uw@php.net:

> ...use `mysqli_set_charset()` to set the charset and then `SET NAMES` to change the collation.

He/she also links to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-set-character-set.html

> This function is used to set the default character set for the current connection. The string `csname` specifies a valid character set name. The connection collation becomes the default collation of the character set. This function works like the `SET NAMES` statement, but also sets the value of `mysql->charset`, and thus affects the character set used by `mysql_real_escape_string()`

And I'll link to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collate.html which shows how to make queries using whatever collation suits that query.

> With the COLLATE clause, you can override whatever the default collation is for a comparison. COLLATE may be used in various parts of SQL statements. Here are some examples:

- > With `ORDER BY`:
  >   `SELECT k
  >   FROM t1
  >   ORDER BY k COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;`
- > With `AS`:
  >   `SELECT k COLLATE latin1_german2_ci AS k1
  >   FROM t1
  >   ORDER BY k1;`
- > With `GROUP BY`:
  >   `SELECT k
  >   FROM t1
  >   GROUP BY k COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;`
- > With aggregate functions:
  >   `SELECT MAX(k COLLATE latin1_german2_ci)
  >   FROM t1;`
- > With `DISTINCT`:
  >   `SELECT DISTINCT k COLLATE latin1_german2_ci
  >   FROM t1;`
- > With `WHERE`:
  >   `SELECT *
  >   FROM t1
  >   WHERE _latin1 'Müller' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci = k;
  >   SELECT *
  >   FROM t1
  >   WHERE k LIKE _latin1 'Müller' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;`
- > With `HAVING`:
  >   `SELECT k
  >   FROM t1
  >   GROUP BY k
  >   HAVING k = _latin1 'Müller' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;`