# Incorrect updated Chinese text and PHP, MySql

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this sql from the MySql Admin panel:

```
UPDATE CH_HRA_questions SET question = '稱謂' WHERE q_id = 1
```

it works correctly, and in the table I can see the correct Chinese characters.

But when I run the same update statement from PHP, I get:

**ç¨±è¬‚**

The collation of the field is utf8_unicode_ci, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: change your web page's encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the PHP<->MySQL-connection charset.

If you are using the old MySQL API use `mysql_set_charset('utf8_unicode_ci')` ([more](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-set-charset.php)).
If you use the MySQLi API use `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8_unicode_ci')` ([more](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.set-charset.php)).

I also found out that `$mysqli->query('utf8')` can be working ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433760/1485952))...

Comment: or run query `SET NAMES UTF8` right after connection established