# MySQL Query only works within WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I tried extensively to find an answer but my question seems to be too specific.

My query contains latin characters:

```
$mydb->query("SELECT cotação FROM compras");
```

It's working fine when called in a WordPress shortcode, but in a custom php on the same site it gives me this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '??o FROM compras' at line 1

Now, I don't want to just remove the characters because I know the query works and I'd rather understand the problem.

So what's going on here? Thanks.

Comment: [You should read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/1679849) But using non-ASCII characters in table names is a terrible idea if you ask me.

Comment: You can probably enclose the field name in backticks (`)

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work on my local machine, it would not work until I set the collation and `NAMES` to UTF8.  It appears from the wealth of data I find in searching that this is the primary problem people encounter with non-ASCII characters.

To get it to work with my local PDO instance, I did the following:

```
    $pdo->exec("SET collation_connection = utf8_bin");
    $pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    $all = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM temp_cotação LIMIT 5")->fetchAll();
```

You can find more information here:

[PDO cutting off strings at a UTF-8 character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684757/pdo-cutting-off-strings-at-a-utf-8-character)

It seems to me that it would be better to do this globally rather than per connection...I found this to do the `SET NAMES utf8` globaly for each connection:

[How to make PDO run SET NAMES utf8 each time I connect, In ZendFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584676/how-to-make-pdo-run-set-names-utf8-each-time-i-connect-in-zendframework)

To do the same thing in mysqli_, look here:

[php mysql SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' doesn't work with mysqli (solved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433734/php-mysql-set-names-utf8-collate-utf8-unicode-ci-doesnt-work-with-mysqli-s)